# On page scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have followed the instructions to set up on page scrolling on my Wordpress site: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html but it doesn't seem to be working.

**page HTML**

```
<div class="main">
<section>[new_royalslider id="2"]</section>
<section>...</section>
</div>
```

header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".main").onepage_scroll();
</script>
```

I've had a look at inspect element and there are no error messages. The scroll bar doesn't seem to work at all anymore.

[See link](http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/aaaaaaaaa/)

Answer (score 1):

You have imported both the `jquery.onepage-scroll.js`, but also its minified version - `jquery.onepage-scroll.min.js`. Don't include both versions - it is likely creating a Javascript error.

Also, before you run jQuery code, [wrap it in this code:](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".main").onepage_scroll();      
});
```

This is because it is likely the element classed as `main` has not rendered to the DOM yet, so it doesn't exist when the `onepage_scroll()` function is called.

Last potential problem is that I don't see your stysheet - is '.main' even large enough to take multiple pages of the browser?

Comment: I have removed the minified version but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Okay - i added another suggestion.

Comment: It's still not working after making those changes..I checked element inspector and still no errors.

Comment: What's this about: `<section>[new_royalslider id="2"]</section>`

Comment: It's a shortcode for the royal slider plugin used on the site